# Tutorial for embedding UIView into UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

Does anybody on here know a good tutorial for loading coretext into a UIView, which is itself a subview of a UIScrollView (to enable the full text content to be viewed on the device) I have been looking at the problem for a while and cant get my head around it! I can get a UIView as a subview of ScrollView, I can get coretext into a UIView, but i cant seem to get all three working together!

Comment: Ive tried the Ray Wenderlich one, but that isnt loading the view into a scrollview, which is the feature I need

Comment: Well, how about `[scrollView addSubview:view];`?

Comment: sorry my request was slightly vague, i need to get the coretext loaded into the uiview which needs to scroll as a subview of scrollview - i can get the layout (i think) but cant seem to reference the coretext to the subview from the main view controller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=uiview+uiscrollview+tutorial&oq=uiview+uiscrollview+tut&aqs=chrome.1.57j0j60j62l2.5223j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) revealed these:

> #### UIScrollView – A really simple tutorial | [iDevzilla](http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/)
>
> #### How To Use UIScrollView to Scroll and Zoom Content by [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content)
>
> #### How To: UIScrollView with Paging | [iOS Dev Notes](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/)
>
> ### [[...]](https://www.google.com/search?q=uiview+uiscrollview+tutorial&oq=uiview+uiscrollview+tut)

Ultimately, you want `[scrollView addSubview:view];`, but I would need more info to help you with your specific problem.

Comment: that ray wenderlich one is ace, very informative. Turns out its easier to declare the subview in code rather than designing it in the ib. Thankyou.

Comment: Code is almost always easier than IB - when you get used to it.

Comment: Don't forget to set the scrollView to enabled: [_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES]; This had me stuck for hours